# Where can I find an educational game for learning jQuery? (something like regenemies)

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to refine my jQuery skills by means of playing an educational game (for learning jQuery). However, I can't seem to find one because every time I google something with "jQuery" and "game" I get results for jQuery game development. I really want to learn jQuery by playing a game similar to regenemies (http://darevay.com/regenemies/) which I used to learn regular expressions.

Does anyone know of any applications/games out there that quiz you on jQuery selectors and the like? I can see a bunch of jQuery quizzes, but that's not really what I'm looking for...

I wish I could find a site that aggregated tons of programming educational games.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can anyone recommend a good jQuery training course?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442348/can-anyone-recommend-a-good-jquery-training-course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- http://learnjquery.tutsplus.com/
- http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/jquery

Not free

- https://learnable.com/courses/jquery-fundamentals-1132
- http://www.lynda.com/jQuery-tutorials/essential-training/48370-2.html
- http://www.jquery4u.com/news/50-awesome-online-jquery-course/#.T-NBnfV5dIY
- http://jquery-online-training.eventbrite.com/
- http://appendto.com/training
- http://teamtreehouse.com/library/websites/build-an-interactive-website

Also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442348/can-anyone-recommend-a-good-jquery-training-course

Comment: Wouldn't it be incredibly easy to implement a regenemies-like game for jQuery selectors? ...maybe I could make it...